# Why do we compile shaders at runtime in OpenGL 2?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I have been trying to learn OpenGL, specifically for Android. I have seen various tutorials online, and I noticed that many of the tutorials for OpenGL 1.0, or 1.2 do not require compilation of shader programs, while the only tutorials I could find for OpenGL 2.0 all involve creating a custom shader to render shapes in the view.

The process of using a string to hold code (GLSL) and then compiling and linking this code at run-time feels cumbersome (hacky even). Is this necessary because GPU architectures can vary greatly?

Is there a way to use some kind of default shaders that don't require this step (like a built in shader)? I just want to be able to draw primitives like GL_POINTS, GL_LINES, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this necessary because GPU architectures can vary greatly?

Yes indeed and while there has been mentioning of an IR version of shaders there hasn't been a proper consensus about how it should look.

You can use [glShaderBinary](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glProgramBinary) to precompile the shader in a previous run and reuse the compiled output.

Comment: What do you mean by "IR version"? And regarding precompiling, that would mean still compiling during app runtime (at least the first time), right? Or is that something that can be done during development for each GPU type and selectively loaded at run time?

Comment: "Intermediate Representation" essentially byte code. and yes but some optimizations and verifications can then be done before hand.

Comment: Ah, ok. So, code in strings is necessary, and there aren't any sort of "built-in" generic shaders then?